# Where is the email for user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```bash
rails generate scaffold User email:string
```

Model is empty.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
end
```

Controller

```
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    ...
  end
```

Table:

```
create_table :users do |t|
  t.string :email
  t.timestamps
end
```

How it works? And whether there is a plugin for ide to navigate?

Comment: Your question is quite broad. The trick is that your `User` class inherits from `ApplicationRecord` and that inherits from [`ActiveRecord::Base`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html) which provides all the “magic” object to DB record mapping. I suggest reading: [Active Record Basics in the official Rails Guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html).

Comment: From [`ActiveRecord::Base`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html): _"Active Record objects don’t specify their attributes directly, but rather infer them from the table definition with which they’re linked."_

Comment: You’ll want a Rails tutorial. Not sure what you mean by “navigate”, where do you want to go from/to? You’ll rarely need to mess with the table def. If you’re asking how do you know what props a model has—that gets interesting very quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby on Rails impelements the [Active Record Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern)

This is the [full guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html) of Rails Active Record